# MySql Query to search a string 'SAMSUNG' if someone mistakenly types 'SAMSUMG'

Tags: mysql, search

I have a search box in where customers can type in anything to search in our database. The database contains products from different brands, for example 'samsung', 'micromax', etc. While typing in the search box a customer can mistakenly type 'samsumg' instead of 'samsung'. My Question is what should be the query to return all products that contain 'samsung' in its name.
Thanks.

Comment: do you mean all product contains samsung or samsumg? or just samsung?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this:

`SELECT ... WHERE product SOUNDS LIKE 'samsumg'`

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use

```
... where product LIKE 'SAMSU_G'
```

You can find more about pattern matching for MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

Comment: How is it supposed to know that you need to put `_` in exactly that position? "a customer can *mistakenly type*"

Answer (score 0):

Use the Soundex function to search for phonetically similar words :

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE soundex( sounds ) = soundex( 'samsumg' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ... WHERE product LIKE 'samsu%'
```